# path does not work if there is a matchpath gatsby

Tags: gatsby

When creating pages with createPage. Setting the path and matchPath with added parameters. I would expect both will resolve the same component layout and render the same content. In my case, only the matchPath is rendering components and the original path does not render any.

```
createPage({
     path: slug,
     matchPath: slugWithParameters, //Only this renders component
     component: layout,
     context: {
          id
     },
});
```

This is my reach Router:

```
<Router>
    <PrivateRoute page={Page} path={slugWithParameters} {...props} />
</Router>
```

Shouldn't the path and matchPath render the same content? Do I need to support the original path in the Router as well?

**EDIT:**

**slug** can be: "/", "/about", "/products"

**slugWithParameters** can be: "/:id", "/:id/about", "/:id/products"

Comment: How the `slug` does look like?

Comment: Hi @FerranBuireu, thanks for the comment. slug can be "/", "/about", "/products". slugWithParameters can be "/:id", "/:id/about", "/:id/products"